# Flex: Expand AdvancedDataGrid Tree Column programmatically

Tags: apache-flex, tree, advanceddatagrid

Does anyone know how to programmatically expand the nodes of an AdvancedDataGrid tree column in Flex? If I was using a tree I would use something like this:

```
dataGrid.expandItem(treeNodeObject, true);
```

But I don't seem to have access to this property in the AdvancedDataGrid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AdvancedDataGrid has an expandItem() method too:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/AdvancedDataGrid.html#expandItem()

Answer (score 5):

Copy the sample found at the aforementioned url and call this function:

```
private function openMe():void
{
    var obj:Object = gc.getRoot();
    var temp:Object = ListCollectionView(obj).getItemAt(0);
    myADG.expandItem(temp,true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also open nodes by iterating through the dataProvider using a cursor. Here is how I open all nodes at a specified level:

```
    private var dataCursor:IHierarchicalCollectionViewCursor;

    override public function set dataProvider(value:Object):void
    {
        super.dataProvider = value;

        /* The dataProvider property has not been updated at this point, so call 
            commitProperties() so that the HierarchicalData value is available. */
        super.commitProperties();

        if (dataProvider is HierarchicalCollectionView)
            dataCursor = dataProvider.createCursor();
    }

    public function setOpenNodes(numLevels:int = 1):void
    {
        dataCursor.seek(CursorBookmark.FIRST);

        while (!dataCursor.afterLast)
        {
            if (dataCursor.currentDepth < numLevels)
                dataProvider.openNode(dataCursor.current);
            else
                dataProvider.closeNode(dataCursor.current);

            dataCursor.moveNext();
        }

        dataCursor.seek(CursorBookmark.FIRST, verticalScrollPosition);

        // Refresh the data provider to properly display the newly opened nodes
        dataProvider.refresh();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Would like to add here that the AdvancedDataGrid, in spite of having an `expandAll()` method, has a property called `displayItemsExpanded`, which set to `true` will expand all the nodes.

For expanding particular children, the `expandChildrenOf()` and `expandItem()` methods can be used, as can be verified from the links given above.